# can not reference a textinput value by variable in jquery post method

Tags: jquery

I want send data by jquery ajax post method.I am trying to reference a input of a form by variable. But unsuccessful.Here is the code..

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function abc(parameter)
{  
 $.post('test1.php',{id:parameter.parameter.value},
      function(output)
      {
         $('div').html(output).show();            

         })
}
</script>
<?php
for ($i=1;$i<=3;$i++)
{   $j=$i+1;
echo "<form name='$i'><div>$i</div><input name='$i' type='hidden' value='$j'/><input type='button'value='Accept' onclick='abc($i)'></form>";
}
?>
```

I want to get output 3 when i press second button. My firebug console say "undefined parameter.parameter" what should i do?please advise me.Thanks in advance....
Here is my test1.php code..

```
  if (isset($_POST['id']))
 {     $id=$_POST['id'];
   echo "Got $id";
  }
```

Comment: You're just passing `$1` to the `abc()` function, which is meaningless given the code you've provided. I think you meant to pass the element through to the function, then get its value, in which case you want `parameter.value` rather than `parameter.parameter.value` but even then you'll need to correct the way you're passing the element to `abc()`.

Comment: By the way, you should take some time to format the code of your question. The indentation looks a little weird at times.

Answer (score 0):

In your comment you said that you wanted to send the value of the textbox. Since the textbox is rendered with an onclick like this: `onclick='abc($i)'`, e.g. `onclick='abc(2)'` when `$i=2`, you will need to locate correct textbox in the `abc` function, that is the textbox with name `2`:

```
function abc(parameter) {
    var textboxValue = $("input[name='" + parameter + "']").val();
    $.post('test1.php',{id: textboxValue}, function(output) {
        $('div').html(output).show();
    });
}
```

Comment: i want to send the value of texbox

Comment: i think i will get the value of second textbox from 2.2.value

Comment: Great, happy to help! Can you please accept this answer so that the question is closed?

Comment: Hey @SovonMainul, please accept this answer if it solved the problem of your question so that its not left open.